# Credit Card Testing (Paypal Payflow API)

Tags: manual-testing, web-application, api-testing

I am testing the payment gateway of my e-commerce website.

Our developers are using PayPal Payflow API’s, i.e., the card processing (gathering/saving the card details) will be happening in our website frontend.

And when the user clicks ‘Submit Order’, our page will validate using the PayPal Payflow API’s and give the user an alert that the payment is successful or not.

But as a tester,

*how do I test that?*

I need to check whether the amount has been deducted from a credit card and credited to merchant account of client.

Comment: What is holding you back to test? You can create some virtual credit-cards and execute the process not? Just get a sign-off on the budget =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you really need to test money has been deducted? You should trust PayPal tested their end of the payment system. If not get some real credit-cards and test the full flow.

PayPal has some guides how to do the testing, it includes example of test credit-card numbers, with this you should be able to test the whole flow, except the money part.

- Test integration with the Payflow Gateway: https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1493
- PayPal Sandbox Testing Guide: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/ug_sandbox/

Answer (score 2):

Every time I have implemented a payment system integration, there are two major phases of testing.

First is the QA testing, which ensures the program flow is correct. There may also be scripted responses to test. For example, an amount ending in $X.42 will result in a decline: does the application behave correctly?

What you are referring to is typically validated during certification testing with the payment processor. QA is typically on the phone or Skype with a representative from the payment processor (AJB, FDMS, PayPal, et al). As you run through the scenarios, the other company's representative will validate the results on their end (in a test box, of course). Together, you will validate that both systems are working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I would divide the testing into two parts:

- The forms processing on your site
  This is where you should write UI test cases
- Production Monitoring.
  Separate from testing you should consider having a system that sees if the PayPal API is available

Answer (score 0):

Usually when testing payments via PayPal, Stripe, WorldPay etc., I develop some test cases for the different scenarios that are possible and that require testing. These include happy path tests where the test card details are all ok and a successful payment expected. Then error tests are added, to test for conditions such as card declined, incorrect cvc, expired card, processing error etc.

In each case, I would trust that the code/result coming back from the payment processor is correct and to be trusted, as that is entirely in their hands and a certain element of trust has to be given.

Therefore, I wouldn't be testing deductions from credit cards, credits to merchant accounts etc. as that is handled by the payment processor.